# CGFloat comparison wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, quartz-graphics

in my app i'm checking if the the x-value of a CGPoint is different than zero in an if-statement. however, the app enters the if-statement although the x-value of the point is zero. here is the code:

```
CGPoint previousPoint;

     if (previousPoint.x != 0) {
            NSLog(@"YES");
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, previousPoint.x, previousPoint.y);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 150+(40*[[[self.grades objectAtIndex:i] semesterGPA] doubleValue]), 59+(40*(i+1)));
        }
    }
```

After running the app "YES" is printed although it shouldn't as previousPoint is (0.000000, 0.000000) how can i fix this?

Comment: its a float value and it seems that you compare float (x) to int (0). use 0.0

Comment: Is `previousPoint` ever given a value? Also, you should be using `if (previousPoint.x != 0.0f`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure that `previousPoint` is initiated with some value! And compare float to float and not to int.

```
CGPoint previousPoint;

     if (previousPoint.x != 0.0f) {
            NSLog(@"YES");
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, previousPoint.x, previousPoint.y);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 150+(40*[[[self.grades objectAtIndex:i] semesterGPA] doubleValue]), 59+(40*(i+1)));
        }
    }
```